# Autowiring not happening in spring

Tags: spring

I have been trying to use autowiring, but it fails to get autowired. Here is the code snippet,

App context file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shapes" />

    <bean id = "triangle" class = "com.shapes.Triangle" autowire="byName"></bean>
```

Triangle class:

```
@Component
public class Triangle implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("In draw");

    }

}
```

Main class :

```
public class MainShapes {

    @Autowired
    private Triangle triangle;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainShapes shapes  = new MainShapes();
        shapes.triangle.draw();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you initiating you `App Context ` file which initiates your autowired bean? You have to first load `context` to initialize the bean using `ClassPathxmlApplicationcontext()`

Comment: Check this example :  http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 2):

Only spring-managed beans will get autowired automatically (unless you use some kind of AOP).

In your main class you create `MainShapes` manually, and there is nothing related to spring except annotations.

It won't magically work that way. You probably want to retrieve your `MainShapes` from spring ioc container (and make sure that it is in app context) ...